# idiom along the lines of "you get more relatives as you get famous"

Tags: idioms

Overheard something that sounds like "うれるど親戚 {しんせき} かくれる"(must be mistakes somewhere since there's no search result for the phrase). Kind of a sarcastic/joking idiom, saying that as a person gets famous, they will appear to have more distant relatives (because people want to be related to the famous person). What might be the correct form of this idiom/is such idioms widely used/accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you heard 売れると親戚が増える? [売れる](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A3%B2%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B) means "(for a celebrity/artist/etc) to be popular/successful" and [増える](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A2%97%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B) means "to increase". This is **not** a traditional idiom at all, but I've heard jokes along the lines of this several times. There are many variations since this is not a fixed idiom like "when in Rome", but you can search with 売れると親戚が増える or [有名になると親戚が増える](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E6%9C%89%E5%90%8D%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E8%A6%AA%E6%88%9A%E3%81%8C%E5%A2%97%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B) and find many relevant results.

Comment: that sounds like it, thanks a lot!